# iterator in C++ stl list not pointing to the middle of a list.. how would I solve this?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make miditer point to the middle of the list, I keep getting an error when I try to do this.. Using a STL list, anyone got any ideas for this?

```
    std::list<PlayerNode>::iterator startiter, miditer, enditer;

    startiter = wall_list_.begin();

    miditer = Psnake_parts_.begin() + new_size_; // Trying to point to half of a list.

    enditer = Psnake_parts_.end();


    if (x_ == poison_.getX() && y_ == poison_.getY()){  //trying to make the list remove half.


    wall_list_.splice (startiter, Psnake_parts_, miditer, enditer);


    }
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error " Sharing that **exact** error text would productive. We can't read your mind. As a bonus, we also can't compile your code.

Comment: What's with all the questions asking about errors that don't even bother saying what the error is?

Comment: My assumption is that the error is a compiler error as list iterators do not support `+` or `-`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::list` iterators are [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) and so can only be incremented and decremented. You would need a container like a `std::vector` if you want a random access iterator that supports addition and subtraction.

Example for clarification:

```
std::list<int> myList = someFunctionToFillMyListWithData();
auto listIter = myList.begin();

// You can do this because list iterators are bidirectional
listIter++;
listIter--;

// You cannot do this because they are not random access
auto someOtherPointIter = listIter + 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Iterator Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) reference and look very closely at the [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) details.  This should resolve the goal of moving an iterator more than a single position.

Comment: Good call.  I had forgotten about std::advance.

Comment: @pstrjds Thanks.  I have also seen (never tried before) that a Bidirectional iterator can be used to move an iterator backwards with the `advance` method.  The `Distance` value has to be negative of course.  However, if `Distance` is negative for an InputIterator, then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: There's also [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) if you want to create a new iterator given a starting iterator and an offset. The code in the question can be rewritten as `miditer = std::next(Psnake_parts_.begin(), new_size_);`

Comment: Those are within the C++11 standard.  user3426187 has not supplied enough detail stating a C++11 compiler is being used.  The tag is present, but ...